# How to fetch the only iPhone contact list in ios7?

Tags: ios, abaddressbook, abaddressbooksource

Please tell me how to fetch only iPhone contact list in ios7. When I login with facebook the facebook contact list has been imported in contact list so I just want iPhone contact mobile list number?

Answer (score 0):

You need to iterate all the sources available in the address book, and only pick the ones you want to read from. Then you can retrieve a list of contacts from those sources.